# Why I am getting file not found exception while copying file on HDFS using Pydoop?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

My Python code using Pydoop API is show below. I have a text file `/home/progen/test.txt`. While running the script to copy this file to HDFS, I am getting an error.

```
  import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs

     local_path = '/home/progen/test.txt'

     hdfs_path = '/spark_user/' 

     host = 'master'

     port = 9000

     hdfsobj = hdfs.hdfs(host, port, user='spark', groups=['supergroup'])

     hdfsobj.copy(local_path, hdfsobj, hdfs_path)
```

## I am getting the Error: "File does no exist"

```
hdfsCopyImpl(src=/home/progen/test.txt, dst=/spark_user/, deleteSource=0): FileUtil#copy error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /home/progen/test.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hdfs.py", line 8, in <module>
    hdfsobj.copy(local_path, hdfsobj, hdfs_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydoop/hdfs/fs.py", line 304, in copy
    return self.fs.copy(from_path, to_hdfs, to_path)

hdfsCopyImpl(src=/home/progen/test.txt, dst=/spark_user/, deleteSource=0): FileUtil#copy error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /home/progen/test.txt

at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:337)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hdfs.py", line 8, in <module>
    hdfsobj.copy(local_path, hdfsobj, hdfs_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydoop/hdfs/fs.py", line 304, in copy
    return self.fs.copy(from_path, to_hdfs, to_path)
```

Comment: can you check `ls  /home/progen/test.txt` that file really exists?

Comment: yes exists... but giving error